# Dispaly shipping charges inside the cart page Table

Tags: cart, shipping

in cart page, you can see there is an option to find shipping charges :

[image]

we customized this and now its displaying like this :

Now i want to display that block in place of text "Here", you can see "Here" text in below image.

[image]

we are using following code for finding shipping charges in cart page. i copied the entire code and placed this code in place of "Here" but i got error as in following image :

[image]

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml

<?php /** @var $this Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Shipping */ ?>
<div class="shipping">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('') ?></h2>
    <div class="shipping-form">
       <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimatePost') ?>" method="post" id="shipping-zip-form">

            <ul class="form-list">
            <div style="display:none">

               <li>
                    <label for="country"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                        <?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect($this->getEstimateCountryId()) ?>
                    </div>

                </li>
            </div>

            <?php //if($this->getStateActive()): ?>
            <!--
                <li>
                    <label for="region_id"<?php if ($this->isStateProvinceRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isStateProvinceRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" style="display:none;"<?php echo ($this->isStateProvinceRequired() ? ' class="validate-select"' : '') ?>>
                            <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                        </select>
                       <script type="text/javascript">
                       //<![CDATA[
                           $('region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  "<?php echo $this->getEstimateRegionId() ?>");
                       //]]>
                       </script>
                       <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getEstimateRegion()) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text" style="display:none;" />
                   </div>
                </li>
            -->
            <?php //endif; ?>
            <?php if($this->getCityActive()): ?>
                <li>
                    <label for="city"<?php if ($this->isCityRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isCityRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input class="input-text<?php if ($this->isCityRequired()):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" id="city" type="text" name="estimate_city" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getEstimateCity()) ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
                <li>
                    <label for="postcode"<?php if ($this->isZipCodeRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isZipCodeRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('Check Delivery') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input class="input-text validate-postcode<?php if ($this->isZipCodeRequired()):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" type="text" id="postcode" name="estimate_postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getEstimatePostcode()) ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="buttons-set">
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Check') ?>" onclick="coShippingMethodForm.submit()" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Check') ?></span></span></button>
            </div>





        </form>



        <!-- Prashant -->
     <td>


    <?php if (($_shippingRateGroups = $this->getEstimateRates())): 

       if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyShipMessage()){
             echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyShipMessage();
             Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsMyShipMessage();
        }

    endif; ?>



    </td>

    <!-- Prashant end -->


        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            new RegionUpdater('country', 'region', 'region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>);
        //]]>
        </script>

        <?php if (($_shippingRateGroups = $this->getEstimateRates())): ?>
        <form id="co-shipping-method-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimateUpdatePost') ?>">
            <dl class="sp-methods">
                <?php foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <ul>
                        <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                            <li<?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()) echo ' class="error-msg"';?>>
                               <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getErrorMessage()) ?>
                               <?php else: ?>
                                    <input name="estimate_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getCode()) ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio" />
                                    <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle()) ?>
                                    <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                                    <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
                                    <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                                        (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    </label>
                               <?php endif ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
            <div style="display:none;">
                <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Total') ?>" class="button" name="do" 
                value="<?php echo $this->__('Update Total') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update Total') ?></span></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var coShippingMethodForm = new VarienForm('shipping-zip-form');
            var countriesWithOptionalZip = <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getCountriesWithOptionalZip(true) ?>;

            coShippingMethodForm.submit = function () {
                var country = $F('country');
                var optionalZip = false;

                for (i=0; i < countriesWithOptionalZip.length; i++) {
                    if (countriesWithOptionalZip[i] == country) {
                        optionalZip = true;
                    }
                }
                if (optionalZip) {
                    $('postcode').removeClassName('required-entry');
                }
                else {
                    $('postcode').addClassName('required-entry');
                }
                return VarienForm.prototype.submit.bind(coShippingMethodForm)();
            }





        //]]>
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using $this so it is an instance of particular block related to template file.

Are you trying to use shipping.phtml code in another file

so `$this->isStateProvinceRequired()`

Change to

Mage::getBlock('checkout/cart_shipping')->isStateProvinceRequired()

change all **$this** which use like **$this->isStateProvinceRequired()** change as above code.

Comment: some css problems happened now , please check [here](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-nx0-small.html) by adding product to cart and got for cart page

Comment: can i use calling static blocks for phtml to get solution ?

Comment: Yes you can use {{block type="checkout/cart_shipping" template="your-template- name"}}

Comment: i tried like this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105200/calling-a-phtml-file-in-static-block-and-vice-versa-is-not-working/105229#105229

Comment: Now its displaying UI part, but functionailty is working. means if i click on "check" button, shipping charges are not working.

Comment: visit [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-nx0-small.html) and click on "Buy Now" button you can see  2 "check" butttons,

one inside table, type"560043" and check its not giving shipping charges. but when we use the "check"

button present below, than it will work.

Comment: You are using form inside form so it will trigger error.

Comment: please check these code and let me know what error i did : 

default.phtml = http://pastebin.com/bBjZBpyd

shipping.phtml = http://pastebin.com/WXAAnCdW

Comment: shipping.phtml => http://pastebin.com/172UqTXe i did't placed your code inside <form> but still its not working.

IS i need to place between <form> ? i am not using form inside form.